# How to parse String and send multiple values to constructor

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, constructor

I am doing a class assignment where I have to parse a given string into different types of variables. The different variables are: **Name, Surname, Date of Birth, City of Birth**. After this is done, the variables needs to be sent to the constructor of the **class Person**.

I am stuck with how to assign the three different values to a variable and then send it back to the constructor. I have tried declaring an array for each variable and then filling it with for loop with the values but then I ran into trouble finding a neat way of declaring its length plus I think I would need to convert the array back to strings in order to pass the values to the constructor and the resulting code would be messy. Is there a simpler way of doing this?

I don't know if this will change anything in the code but after I passed the values to the constructor, I need to send that object to a List collection and use it to print the details about each person.

Here is my current code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Given string to parse
    String text = "John.Davidson/05051988/Belgrade Michael.Barton/01011968/Krakov Ivan.Perkinson/23051986/Moscow";

    String[] parsArray = text.split("[ /.]+");

    // Results from parsing
    for (Object s: parsArray)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    } 

    for (int i = 0; i<parsArray.length; i+=4)
    {
        String firstName = parsArray[i];
        String lastName = parsArray[i+1];
        String birthPlace = parsArray[i+3];
        System.out.println("\nFirst name: " + firstName + "\nLast name: " + lastName + "\nCity of birth: " + birthPlace);
    }           
 }
 }
```

**Class Person** and its constructor:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Person {
String name;
String surname;
LocalDate dob;
String placeOfBirth;

public Person(String name, String surname, LocalDate dob, String placeOfBirth)
{
this.name = name;
this.surname = surname;
this.dob = dob;
this.placeOfBirth = placeOfBirth;
}  
}
```

Comment: *"I am stuck with how to assign the three different values to a variable"* Really?? Your code does it, e.g. `String firstName = parsArray[i]`. You just assigned value to a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `ArrayList` to store the `Person` objects

```
DateTimeFormatter dobFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMuuuu");
ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList <Person> ();
for (int i = 0; i<parsArray.length; i+=4)
    {
        String firstName = parsArray[i];
        String lastName = parsArray[i+1];
        LocalDate dob = LocalDate.parse(parsArray[i+2], dobFormatter);
        String birthPlace = parsArray[i+3];
        System.out.println("\nFirst name: " + firstName + "\nLast name: " + lastName + "\nCity of birth: " + birthPlace);
        list.add (new Person (firstName, lastname, dob, birthPlace));
    }
```

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, I did not notice that `dob` existed.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thank you for posting your solution and it worked like a charm. I finished the DateTimeFormatter part before seeing this answer but it still helped! I just covered the essentials of ArrayList but this what you did solved everything in one single simple line.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but I think you'll make some additional headway if you can structure your code in a way that helps you isolate problems.  The goal is to break the problem into small enough pieces to tackle in simple, cohesive functions.  I like to sketch out classes or methods before trying to fill in their details.  But first, I start by talking my way through the problem.

The goal is to convert a single line of text into a collection of type-specific Person objects.  The input uses a single space a record delimiter, '.' periods to separate the first name from the surname, and '/' slashes to separate the other fields within the record.  Ahhh ... a classic.

The first step is to merely isolate the blocks of text that deal with each individual record.  I can see that because the first thing I noticed about the input text was that it used spaces to separate information about different persons.  No need to try to write code that tries to swallow the whale in one bite, right?

```
String[] parseRecords(String input) {
    return input.split("[ ]+");
}
```

Now that records are isolated from one another, we need a method to produce a Person record from a block of text that only contains a single record i.e. a subset of the original input that only contains information about a single person.  In my problem description, I noticed that both '.' and '/' are used as field delimiters so we can separate into fields on either.  There are many other ways to write this regular expression but I've copied your approach used in the question.

```
Person parsePersonFromString(String text) {
  String[] fields = text.split("[./]+");
  LocalDate dob = /* something with field[2] */
  return new Person(fields[0], fields[1], dob, fields[3]);
}
```

Notice the split array of Strings should have length 4.  The first two fields are names so they already in a String type.  Same goes for the city field.  The date field gets a bit trickier because you have a String and you want a LocalDate.  Since this is homework I'll leave the details to you, but keep in mind if you run into trouble this too is something you could break down into a simpler problem!

```
LocalDate parseDateFromField(String field) {
}
```

Comment: I enjoyed reading your thorough explanation and you are so right, "no need to try to write code that tries to swallow the whale in one bite". This is something that I always try to do and then tend to get lost so I will take your good advice for future. Cheers!